# Java extras bundle is returning null values

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

My bundle is returning null strings for the contained extras. Not NPEs, actual "null" values. Any ideas on why this would be happening?

**new bundle**

```
                        String u = null;
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ******.class);
                        u = api.companyData.link.get(position);
                        Log.d("URL++++++++++++++++++++", u);
                        b.putString("graphic", api.companyData.graphic);
                        b.putString("name", api.companyData.name);
                        b.putString("url", u);
                        i.putExtras(b); 
                        startActivity(i);
```

The log statement is returning the url fine.

**Receiver of bundle**

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
         Log.d("EXTRAS", extras.getString("name")+extras.getString("graphic")+extras.getString("link"));
```

***D/EXTRAS  ( 4698): nullnullnull***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always do it this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ******.class);
i.putExtra("url", u);
```

and then

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

I've never tried it your way, but if you [look at the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29) for `putExtras(Bundle)`, it says:

> Add a set of extended data to the intent. The keys must include a
>   package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use
>   names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

That you're not doing that may be the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 1):

put the objects in the intent directly, e.g.

```
Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ******.class);
i.putExtra("graphic", ...);
i.putExtra("name", ...);
i.putExtra("url", ....);
```

Then in the receiver activity:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("graphic");
getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

Comment: Im still getting nullnullnull though :/

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in the method names: should be putExtra(key, value) in intent and getStringExtra(key) in getIntent().

Comment: No i knew what you meant. Ive used it before. Still returning nullnullnull though

Comment: Can you put a logging before startActivity and make sure the intent extras are not null. e.g. print out what the value of api.companyData.graphic and api.companyData.name are.